# gradle: could not find method apply<>

Tags: gradle

I am trying to create a build script using gradle to build a android project and using plugins from eclipse and android but it doesnt seem to work and failes with the following error when I run `gradle eclipse`:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RssUnified'.
Cause: Could not find method apply() for arguments [{plugin=eclipse}] on root project 'RssUnified'.
```

Here is my build script:

```
//apply eclipse plugin
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

//apply android plugin
apply plugin: 'android'

task hello << {
    String value = 'wagwan'

    println 'Hello world!' + value.toUpperCase()
}

//setup external dependancy plugins we will use to build a android application
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'
}
```

Gradle exception thrown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/BootstrapMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.BootstrapMain
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.gradle.BootstrapMain.  Program will exit.
```

I downloaded full gradle version from this link: http://www.gradle.org/downloads

Comment: `dependendcies` is spelled wrong, fyi.

Comment: cheers just saw that. the error doesnt state that though!

Comment: Still diddnt work. still get same error

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but have you installed the plugin? :)

Comment: How? i have installed gradle, eclipse id, android sdk and eclipse IDE plugins for android and gradle

Comment: What's the Gradle version you are running your build script with? Please execute the gradle command with the `-v` option and add the output to your post.

Comment: updated post with resuls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 0.8 did not support the `apply` syntax for plugins yet. Starting with version 0.9 the `apply` method was introduced. A similar issue is described in this [post](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Thinking-about-dipping-my-feet-td1434906.html).

Version 0.8 is pretty old. I'd highly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Gradle. That should definitely fix your problem.

Comment: i downloded the 1.2 zip and installed that? how come it contains 0.8?

Comment: When you say you installed it what exactly did you do? Did you set the `PATH` environment variable correctly? I just downloaded Gradle 1.2 and executing the `gradle` command renders the correct version for me.

Comment: yea i set the path variable correctly. i only have one copy of gradle installed. i never downloaded any previous ones

Comment: edit: seems like there was another gradle installed so i deleted it

i now get a exception when running gradle, see updated post

Comment: Given that you are [reporting other issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119996/gradle-cant-find-classpath-for-android-plugin) on your build now it seems like you got past your initial problem mentioned in this post.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? I am getting the same issue with the exception.