# Gradle can't find classpath for android plugin

Tags: android, gradle

i am getting this error saying it cant find the classpath related to a android plugin. using gradle 1.2 .

here is the error:

```
Could not find method classpath() for arguments [org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1]
```

here is my `build.gradle` file

```
//setup external dependency plugins we will use to build a android application
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

//apply eclipse plugin
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

//apply android plugin
apply plugin: 'android'

apply plugin: 'maven'

task hello << {
    String value = 'wagwan'
    println 'Hello world!' + value.toUpperCase()
}
```

Thanks

edit: new error i recieve now:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve group:org.gradle.api.plugins, module:gradle-android-plugin, version:1.2.1.
  Required by:
      :RssUnified:unspecified
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-android-plugin/1.2.1/gradle-android-plugin-1.2.1.pom'.
   > Could not GET 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/gradle/api/plugins/gradle-android-plugin/1.2.1/gradle-android-plugin-1.2.1.pom'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: I do not get the error message mentioned above in your edit. The plugin can be downloaded successfully. I ran the same code with Gradle 1.2.

Comment: I think my cmd prompt is not using the correct internet proxy at work. any ideas on how i can change internet proxy that is used for cmd.exe in windows 7?

Comment: You can [set up a HTTP proxy for Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html) in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As shown in the guide, the `dependencies { classpath ... }` block has to go inside `buildscript { ... }`. Only for the build script, a configuration named `classpath` is defined.

Comment: Added that and it seems it cant find the necessary pom files. updating my question with the error

Comment: Try `--refresh-dependencies`. It would help if you said which version of Gradle etc.

Comment: --refresh-dependencies still fails

Comment: Well, if you are behind a proxy, you'll have to let Gradle know. For more information, see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).